Python Aiogram Bot (Telegram)
Screenshot bugs..
CODE:
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    await message.answer("Screenshot..")
    with io.BytesIO() as bytes_io:
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        with io.BytesIO() as bytes_io:
            screenshot.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
            byte_io.seek(0)
        await message.answer_photo(photo=byte_io)

pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for SendPhoto
photo.is-instance[InputFile]
  Input should be an instance of InputFile [type=is_instance_of, input_value=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000019F5CB3AAC0>, input_type=BytesIO]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/is_instance_of
photo.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000019F5CB3AAC0>, input_type=BytesIO]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/string_type

I'm tried a lot of (and chatgpt didn't help..)
